# И снова WinSock. UDP. Прием данных.

Tags: c++builder, udp, winsock, c++

До сих пор мучаюсь с изучением WinSock. Уже давно получилось послать команду серверу, но теперь не получается получить от него ответ. Буфер пишет какой-то мусор.

Дано: файл **Unit1.cpp**, **sendrecieve.cpp**, **sendrecieve.h**.
Требуется: после отправки серверу команды getstatus получить строку со всякими параметрами сервера.

***Unit1.cpp***:
Код занесен в секундный таймер.

```
char buf[1024];
sendCMD();
receiveINF(buf);
Memo1->Lines->Add(AnsiString(buf));
```

***sendrecieve.h***:
Две переменные для структуры sockaddr_in для функции sendCMD, которая посылает команду getstatus серверу и заголовки функций передачи/приема инфы.

```
extern char *serverIP;
extern int serverPORT;

void sendCMD();
void sendCMD(char *command);
void receiveINF(char *buf);
```

***sendrecieve.cpp***:
В функции receiveINF(char *buf) я попробовал сделать прием сокета, и вдобавок чтобы он был асинхорнный. В буфер, как я уже писал выше, идет какой-то мусор. Где-то я что-то делаю не так. Вот только не могу понять, где.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include "sendreceive.h"
#include <winsock2.h>

#define WM_ONSOCKET WM_USER+1

void sendCMD()
{
    ...
}

void sendCMD(char *command)
{
    ...
}

void receiveINF(char *buf)
{
    int iResult = 0;

    WSADATA wsd;
    SOCKET RecvSocket;

    struct sockaddr_in RecvAddr;
    int RecvAddrSize = sizeof (RecvAddr);

// Инициализируем сокет
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,0), &wsd);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR)
    {
        ShowMessage("WSAStartup filed");
    }

// Создаем принимающий сокет для приема датаграм
    RecvSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (RecvSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        ShowMessage("Socket failed");
    }

//ВЫЗЫВАЕМ ФУНКЦИЮ, которая сделает нашу функцию АСИНХРОННОЙ. Где-то тут  
//точно есть косяк, о нём после описания данного файла. Скорее всего
//это: Application->Handle надо чем-то заменять. 
//И еще я не разобрался, что же такое WM_ONSOCKET (сверху он в define определен)
//p.s. эту функцию взял на просторах msdn и интернета, по этому не понял, что это
//за зверь. Может есть на что её поменять?
    WSAAsyncSelect(RecvSocket, Application->Handle, WM_ONSOCKET, FD_READ);

// Вызываем функцию для приема датаграм
    iResult = recvfrom(RecvSocket, buf, 1024, 0, (SOCKADDR *) & RecvAddr,
                                                               &RecvAddrSize);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        ShowMessage("Ошибка приема");
    }

// Закрываем сокет, когда приняли датаграммы
    iResult = closesocket(RecvSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        ShowMessage("Ошибка закрытия сокета");
    }

//Очищаем все за собой, и выходим
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Собственно, косяк заключается в следующем:
Когда запускаю программу, то в Memo1 ничего не пишется, но стоит мне мышкой навести на какое-нибудь окно, или кнопку любую, в Мемо1 будет писаться всякий мусор, видимо, из буфера. Причем если навести на кнопку курсор, и никуда не убирать его, то т.н. мусор будет все время одинаковый. Иногда, правда проскакивает "мусор", который, похоже, нужен мне - он начинается с юяяяя и дальше мусор (яяяя, это байты FF в UDP пакете, если точнее, то \xff\xff\xff\xff).
И вопрос - я вообще правильно буфер подсовываю?:) Хотя делал strcat, в мемо с него всё нормально прочиталось.

Comment: Что-то я bind() не заметил. Из очереди какого порта Вы читаете recvfrom() ?

Comment: бинд был, но я его убрал. Он нужен ведь если я сервер, или не так? По крайней мере, где-то увидел реализацию без него. Да и в принципе когда он был, было всё то же самое.

Comment: Точно, сейчас глянул сниффером, он посылает getstatus, потом по ICMP отсылает всю пришедшую с серва инфу ему назад, и в пакете написано - Destanation Unreachable. Буду разбираться с биндом сейчас.

Comment: Кстати, интересно - у меня команда sendto создает сокет, отправляет сообщение серверу, сокет закрывает, очищает его. По этому же принципе действует и функция приема пакета с сервера. Может, в этом и есть проблема? Что начальный сокет, с которого посылалось, закрывается и функция не знает порт, на который прислать пакет.

Comment: конечно порт надо указывать

Comment: да это я уже понял, вот только где? в функции sendCMD? Хотя наврядли...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SOCKET UDP = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP)
    char* val="1";//Это мой старый код хоть убей не помню зачем эта строка
    setsockopt(UDP, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, val, sizeof(val));

    sockaddr_in UDP_addr;
    UDP_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    UDP_addr.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    UDP_addr.sin_port = htons(listenport);

    if( bind(UDP, (sockaddr*)&UDP_addr, sizeof(UDP_addr) ) != SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        cout<<"ok"<<endl;   
    }
    else
        cout<<"error: "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    //тут при бинде для прослушивании могут возникать куча ошибок типа порт занят или что-то ещё

    int r = recvfrom(UDP, buff,sizeof(buff),0, (LPSOCKADDR)&cl, &s);
    if( r != SOCKET_ERROR)
        cout<<"buff = "<<buff<<endl;
    closesocket(UDP);
```

Вот часть моего кода, возможно он тебе поможет. Я просто бросал пакеты по бродкасту поэтому конкретно про код с прослушиванием датаграмм с определенного сервера сказать не могу, что в твоем коде не так.Если надо выкину весь. Возможно мусор из-за твоего зверя(`WSAAsyncSelect(RecvSocket, Application->Handle, WM_ONSOCKET, FD_READ);`) и потому что ты конкретно не указываешь с какого порта слушать.

Comment: В принципе Ваш пример такой же, как и везде практически:) Правда мне броадкаст не надо.
Но всё же есть пару вопросов, которые не понимаю немного - listenport это у Вас (да и вообще) порт, который вы будете биндить на своей системе? Или это порт, с которого должна инфа прийти? (склоняюсь к первому:))
И вот это: (LPSOCKADDR) что это? У меня просто немного по-другому написано, не знаю, что это означает.

Comment: А WSAAsyncSelect я сделал, что бы у меня интерфейс проги не залипал - функция стала асинхронной. Я читал, что можно еще в потоке сделать функцию приёма. Если сейчас не разберусь, завтра попробую поток.

Comment: И что у ваз за переменная cl?

Comment: 1) порт, который вы будете биндить на своей системе на который прийдёт инфа
2) А WSAAsyncSelect я сделал, что бы у меня интерфейс проги не залипал - функция стала асинхронной.
вместо этого создай поток и пусть код в этом потоке принимает что угодно и прога залипать не будет

3) sockaddr_in cl;
в этой структуре будет содержаться адрес от кого пришла датаграмма

Comment: На мой взгляд вместо потоков лучше использовать select() для сокетов, слушающих разные порты. Если одновременно требуется принимать пакеты и ждать ввода не из сокета, то в Винде (насколько я вижу, речь о ней), к сожалению, видимо придется поток создать. Вообще же, программы с потоками на практике отладить сложно.